# Developing in Ada 2012 in Windows 10 for Raspberry Pi

Tags: cross-compilation, ada

I would like to develop in Ada 2012 in Windows 10 for Raspberry Pi.

I would prefer not to install the GPS on the Raspberry Pi, at least , not at first; not least because I want a headless Pi and to install as little as possible, leaving more of the SD card for use as storage space.

I want to do most of the developing in Windows,  abstracting away the hardware until the code is complete and unit tested, then port it to the Raspberry Pi (and possibly some other platforms).

Can I develop on Windows in Ada 2012 for Raspberry Pi ; if so, how?

Ditto, on Raspberry Pi as target?

Comment: I have updated the question. Please, let me know if it is still not clear. Thanks.

Comment: Lol You managed to post that before I posted my update. Hopefully the update clarifies. I could do with some info on how to configure the Ada IDE - either for cross-compilation on an Intel platform, or natively on the Pi. A great bonus would be if someone who codes Ada for the Pi told me which approach they take. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @joan can you help?

Comment: Segmenting and separating HW from higher level logic is generally sound software design, so that part is good. The rest of this question is either too broad or too opinion-based to be a good fit for this site.

Comment: Thanks. I think that I have 2 questions and the second is "primarily opinion based". 1) Can I develop on Windows in Ada 2012 for Raspberry Pi ; if so, how. Ditto, on Raspberry Pi as target 2) off-topic, which one is “better”. I will try to edit the question to remove 2). Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AdaCore IntroducesGNAT GPL 2015 for the Raspberry Pi 2](https://www.adacore.com/press/adacore-introduces-gnat-gpl-2015-for-the-raspberry-pi-2)

> AdaCore, the leading provider of commercial software solutions for the Ada programming language, today released a freely downloadable version of its GNAT GPL Ada cross-development environment for the Raspberry Pi 2 micro-PC running Embedded Linux. With this new cross-development environment, professors, students, hobbyists and others can take advantage of ***Ada*** ***2012***’s reliability, safety and security benefits for their Raspberry Pi 2 applications.